# Still confused about callback function of filesystem in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, fs

I have read some question about callback. But still can't understand.
I write this code to store file into an array.

```
var admList; // The array I want to store in

let readList =(fPath, callback)=>fs.readFile(fPath, 'utf8', (err, fd) => {
      if (err) console.error(fPath+'does not exist');
      callback(fd); // set a callback 
});


readList('admList', function (fd) {
    admList = fd.toString().trim().split('\n'); //using it
});
console.log(admList); // undefined
```

Am I already using a callback function? Why in the console it's still undefined?

Comment: What does it mean " Why can't I make it work"? Are you getting any errors or what?

Comment: Yes, you're using `fd` correctly inside a callback function. But you're likely not using `admList` correctly outside the callback function, in the code that you haven't shown.

Comment: When I using the 'admList', it's still 'undefined'.